# HP CP2025 prints off center, how do I fix it?

Tags: printing, hp

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 and have an issue with my HP printer printing off center.  Every application I've tried both LibreOffice and the PDF application, both print pages with the left and top margins cut short. This leads me to believe that this might be a printer driver issue.  Is anyone else having this problem, or know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with both of my Brother printers:  HL-5370DW and MFC-6490CW.

This issue is acknowledged in the Brother FAQ, but as of yet no resolution:

http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/faq_prn.html#f00107

which suggests that the issue is not printer specific.